# I am unable to make projects in AndroidStudioProjects Folder

Tags: android-studio

[image: Error-01]

If i ignore this warning and continue forward:

[image: Error-02a]
[image: Error-02b]

I dont keep application name "My Application", or any other name that already exists in that directory.

I already have created a lot of projects in that directory without any problem.

I created a new project in AndroidStudio after a week now, so not sure what caused it.

I recently modified Settings to use default gradle wrapper.

And changed gradle-properties to point to gradle-2.10-all.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as the error suggests you already have a project named "my application".
There may be some hidden files or cache of "my application".
Try making a new project with a completely random name.

Comment: as i already mentioned i didnt try making a project with name "My Application"